# Would Woodworking be a good site to ask about old methods?

Tags: discussion

On the Arts & Crafts site, someone asked [How did they make spiral decorations and pearls on old frames?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/how-did-they-make-spiral-decorations-and-pearls-on-old-frames), which was about decorative picture frames made in the 1700s, I assume by hand carving.  Knowledge of the tools and methods from colonial times is a specialty, and it looks like nobody on A&C has that expertise.  People with that knowledge and skill are often employed by museums and working historical landmarks to maintain or recreate items from that era.

I didn't spot a tag here for a dedicated topic.  On the Woodworking site, do you ever get questions about historical techniques, or does the user base include some people who could answer such questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to WSE.  Your question is appropriate and you can use the tag traditional-techniques.  See you there.